# Sending email of dashboard view (Jenkins)

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dashboard, jenkins-email-ext

I have installed the "Dashboard view" plugin on Jenkins. It generates reports as expected. I'd like to notify other team members of these reports via email. I tried using the email-ext plugin and  went through the editable email notification option. But, I couldn't figure out how to attach these reports (generated in the dashboard view). Is something like this possible to do and can someone please guide me how this can be done?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You can also try Catlight to show a [personalized Jenkins build dashboard for each team member](https://catlight.io/a/jenkins-build-monitor)

Comment: Thanks @alex. Catlight is a nice tool for showing personalised dashboards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with "Dashboard view" but I do remember if you use post-build step from email-ext, you can specify the "Attachment" field in "Advanced settings".

If the report generated by "Dashboard view" is an HTML file or some other readable file, I think you can just put the path to the "Attachment" field. If it is something like a json or xml, feel like you should send them the link to the report on Jenkins (usually it is just the link shown in your browser when you view this report).